# HTTP-2 Push Notification using PushSharpHttpTwo

Tags: asp.net, push-notification, http2

I try to send HTTP-2 Push Notification to Apple using PushSharpHttpTwo. This is the code I use:

```
var config = new ApnsHttp2Configuration(ApnsHttp2Configuration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Production, certificate, password);
var broker = new ApnsHttp2ServiceBroker(config);
                
broker.Start();

foreach (Device device in deviceCollection)
{
    broker.QueueNotification(new ApnsHttp2Notification
    {
        DeviceToken = device.Token,
        Topic = "com.nnnn.nnnnnn",
        Payload = JObject.Parse("{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : \"Hello PushSharp!\" } }")
        });
}

broker.Stop();
```

This result in the following error:

*System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at HttpTwo.Http2Connection.d__20.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at HttpTwo.Http2Client.d__19.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at HttpTwo.Http2Client.d__17.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at HttpTwo.Http2Client.d__15.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsHttp2Connection.d__10.MoveNext() in C:\Users\MyUser\Folder\PushSharpHttpTwo\PushSharpHttpTwo-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsHttp2Connection.cs:line 99 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsHttp2ServiceConnection.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\MyUser\Folder\PushSharpHttpTwo\PushSharpHttpTwo-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsHttp2ServiceConnection.cs:line 40*

**After doing some research, it seems like the error has to do with wrong TLS. Or, do anyone know why I get the error above?**

PS: when using the following code (without HTTP-2), Apple Push notification work fine:

```
var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Production, certificate, password);
var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);

apnsBroker.Start();

foreach (Device device in deviceCollection)
{
    apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
    {
        DeviceToken = device.Token,
        Payload = JObject.Parse("{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : '" + alert + "', \"badge\" : '" + AddBadge(device) + "', \"sound\" : \"default\" }}")
    });
}

apnsBroker.Stop();
```

My website run framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for various errors linked to my certificate.

From my experience, it could be that the certificate you are using is expired.
I also had the problem while using the .cert file instead of the .p12 file.